# How to configure Logging via DI in Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I am working on Azure WebJobs (3.0.6) using dotnet core. I referred Microsoft's [Get Started Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started). Per the example I wanted to have a console logging to begin with. The scope of that guide is limited. In my application, I will be using many classes in a different dll. I am not able to figure out how can I add logging in those classes. The sample code is

```
// The main method
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage();
    });

   builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
   {
       b.AddConsole();
    });

    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

// The queue trigger class

```
public class QueueListenerService
{
  public static void QueueListener([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, ILogger logger)
  {
    logger.LogInformation("The logger works here");
    // how can I pass an instance of ILogger in the constructor below
    MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker();
  }
}
```

// MyWorker Class in a different assembly

```
public class MyWorker
{
  public MyWorker(ILogger logger)
  {
    // I want to use logger here being injected
  }
}
```

I have referred several examples of DI in dotnet core console applications and they use service collection approach. I also check [this blog](https://thecodebuzz.com/dependency-injection-console-app-using-generic-hostbuilder/) but to me, this is what I have done and yet my ILogger is not being resolved. It ask me to pass an instance of ILogger when I create MyWorker instance

Comment: I believe you'll want to create a constructor for your QueueListenerService which takes the ILogger as a parameter, this allows for the DI. You'll need to store the injected logger in a private member variable. You'll also need to update the QueueListener method so that it's not static, remove the logger from the parameter, and use the class logger for logging

Comment: Yes, but if I pass the ILogger in constructor of QueueListenerService , it does not get instantiated since the framework is exacting an parameter less constructor and it is not able to pass the dependency,

Comment: @EricMagers Regarding switching from static method to instance, I followed MSDN article. Looks like it was not updated. I found that WebJobs SDK now allow non-static methods so I converted them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the solution. The main thing you need to change is to let the service collection create the `MyWorker` instance for you.

I quickly extended my recent Webjob sample project to include console logging with dependency injection. See [this commit](https://github.com/LXBdev/WebJob-netcore-sample/commit/3e976b6664e565c6c23127705167e6ec6a54053a) for how I added it.

You mainly need to use constructor dependency injection for your `QueueListenerService`.

```
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<QueueListenerService>();
                services.AddScoped<MyWorker>();
            });
```

```
public class QueueListenerService
{
  public QueueListenerService(MyWorker worker){
    _Worker = worker;
  }

  public static void QueueListener([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, ILogger logger)
  {
    logger.LogInformation("The logger works here");

    _Worker.DoStuff()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does allow DI for my service and worker classes, however it still does not allow a constructor DI for ILogger. If I pass ILogger in the constructor of QueueListenerService and MyWorker it does not instantiate them. I, infect add this in my Service collection 
    services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());

Comment: Okay I figured out. I needed to pass the type with ILogger so if i pass ILogger<QueueListenerService> it does work same for MyWorker.
Much appreciate it.